# One list is appended in another list and another list is copy of first list, Why this create infinite nested list of first list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

There are two list r = [9,8,7] and h = [6,5,4] and if h is appended in r,it is working fine as expected.
But if h is newly assigned copy of r, and h is appended in r then it is nested list infinitely,also h is same as r how is that possible, that one append function is causing this?

```
r = [9,8,7]
h = [6,5,4]
h = r
print(r, h)
r.append(h)
print(r)
print(h)

print(r[3][3][3])
print(h[3][3][3])
```

Comment: `h` is *another name for* `r`.  Nothing in your code makes a copy of anything.

Answer (score 0):

By declaring r = h, you are not mentioning that r's value is as same as h's value. Instead you are mentioning both r and h are one and the same. So, after appending h to r, it considers h as r and keeps on appending.

If at all you want to have same value for another variable, you can use

```
h = r.copy()
```

Comment: Thanks bro for explanation , It helps a lot. 

Comment: @PriteshTadvi, Stackoverflows says that when the answer is really helpful, you upvote.
(vote it up!)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up#:~:text=When%20should%20I%20vote%20up,day%2C%20so%20use%20them%20wisely.]